# Extracting just a phone number from a file

Tags: regex, linux, file, unix, grep

I'm sure the answer to this is already online however i don't know what i am looking for. I just started a course in Unix/Linux and my dad asked me to make him something for his work. He has a text file and on every fourth line there is a 10 digit number somewhere. How do i make a list of just the numbers? I assume the file looks something like this:

```
Random junk
Random junk fake number 1234567809
Random junk
My phone number is 1234567890 and it is here random numbers 32131;1231
Random junk
Random junk another fake number 2345432345
Random junk
Just kidding my phone number is here 1234567890 the date is mon:1231:31231
```

I assume its something like grep `[1-9].\{9\}` file but how do i get just lines 4,8,12 etc. Because i tested it and i get all phone numbers on every line. Also how do i get just the number not the whole line?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, even if its pointing me in the right direction so i can research it myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in two steps:

```
$ awk '!(NR%4)' file | grep -Eo '[0-9]{10}'
1234567890
1234567890
```

- `awk '!(NR%4)' file` prints those lines whose number is multiple of 4. It is the same as saying `awk '(NR%4==0) {print}' file`.
- `grep -Eo '[0-9]{10}'` prints the numbers that appear on blocks of 10. Note that `-o` is for "just print the matches" and `-E` to use extended regular expressions.

Or also

```
$ awk '!(NR%4)' file | grep -Eo '[1-9][0-9]{9}' #check if first number is <>0
```

Comment: Learn something every day one here, might be worth using `[1-9]\d{9}` for a little more verification (not `0001239999`).

Comment: Just out of curiosity to save me the time searching on google what is the $ sign for? The command works without it but not with it. I'm new to unix sorry if its obvious.

Comment: Oh no problem at all, @Kevin : ) It is just the prompt of my console. Lines starting with `$` indicate the commands that are being executed, so the rest are just the output. This way it is clear what's the command and what's the result of it.

Comment: @Sam good one! `grep -Po '[1-9][0-9]{9}'` would be good for this, as well as what you comment.

Comment: @fedorqui in your description you said blocks of 8, what does that mean? Thanks again.

Comment: @Kevin typo! I meant blocks of 10 numbers. Just updated, thanks for letting me now!

Comment: digital range `[0-9]` and quantifiers `{10}` are supported by extended regex. `grep -oE` is sufficient

Comment: @fedorqui does what sam put just make it so thee first number isn't a 0? And i think i remeber my dad saying all the area codes are 647 or something, so could i use 647[0-9]{7} instead of [0-9]{10}? *Just tested it, and it works, should help to get rid of random numbers that might be in the file.

Comment: Yes, @Kevin , `647[0-9]{7}` also makes perfect sense. What I recommend you is to create a test file with all different combinations and try to see if it just matches your exact requirements. This way of "playing" is the best to learn!

Comment: @1_CR is there any benefit to using -oE instead of -Po?

Comment: @fedorqui That's what i have been doing this whole time and i'm trying to put things in it to screw it up but this code seems to work perfectly for what i need, thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @fedorqui Sorry to bug you once again but my laptop dies in about 10 minutes so i wanted to get an answer before then, is there any benefit to using `-oE` instead of `-Po`? I asked 1_CR but it seems like he didn't see it for now I looked at the man and it just seems like 2 different options that allow for `{7}` to be used.

Comment: @Kevin I had updated with 1_CR's recommendation. Why? Because (I think) `-P` has way more options than `-E`, so if `-E` alone makes it, using `-P` must be overkilling. So yes, I would go for `-E`.

Comment: fedorqui and @1_CR Seems like you both answered at the same time, thank you both for all your help but unfortunately my computer is about to die so that will be the end of my posts. Have a good one.  Last thought wouldn't `grep -o 647[0-9]\{7\}` also work if avoiding unnecessary options is beneficial (i don't know if that's true or not)

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
sed -nr '0~4{s/.*\b([0-9]{10})\b.*/\1/p}' inputfile
```

Saying `0~4` produces every 4th line starting from the 0th line, i.e. produces every 4th line in the file.  The substitution part is rather obvious.

For your sample input, it'd produce:

```
1234567890
1234567890
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for one number per line, an [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution would involve

```
awk '!(NR%4) && match($0, /[[:digit:]]{10}/){print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' file
```

Comment: +1: With `GNU` awk, using `match()` array abilities - `awk --re-interval '!(NR%4)&&match($0,/([0-9]{10})/,ary)&&$0=ary[1]' file`

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl`:

```
$ perl -nle 'print /([0-9]{10})/ if !($.%4)' file
1234567890
1234567890
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, first, you should know what should be the length of the phone number. You should also consider area codes to be recognized by your code, and possible phone number start numbers. That way you will filter only the most possible true numbers. But if I write "My number is 028 2233 5674... Just kidding, it's 028 2233 9873." Then the code will consider both numbers as correct. So, to solve this completely, if there are fake numbers in the text, is nearly impossible. But an intelligent code, will filter the ones that are most likely to be correct.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i wanted the phone number from every 4th line, i realize now that the text i wrote could confuse but i just put it there to show that the phone number could be anywhere on the line not in a fixed spot. Thanks for the help though, i appreciate it.